# Excluding some specific characters from an entry using Regex

Tags: regex

Actually finding some difficulty with Regex. Can any Regex guru help me to cut this part 01\ from this entry lic01\ense0000.dat   . Actually all the entries have this part and I need something which covers it for all entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?:01\\)");
string TrimmedFileName = rgx.Replace(FileName, "");
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.

Comment: The aim was to remove 01\ from a group of read files. Therefore, the answer shows how one can remove a specific group of characters which are in line. Moreover, I believe that this question will help the ones why have similar issues.